# AnyLogic, error in a batch block agent class cannot be cast to New_agent class

Tags: anylogic

Good day!

I have a model with Source-> Wait-> Batch blocks. The agents are generated by the cyclic event. For one event the random number of agents may be generated, but all of them marked as the same group and have the same creation time.
In a batch block I would like to join the agent with the same creation timestamp. For this purpose I used the wait block, where I calculate the cumulative size of all agents with the same timestamp and set the batchSize. The agents belongs to the class Modality.
However, after Running I get the followiwng error:

*class priority.New_modality cannot be cast to class priority.Modality (priority.New_modality and priority.Modality are in unnamed module of loader 'app')*

What is the reason?

Thank you :)

[![Modality and New Modality

[image: wait]
[image: batch block]

Comment: i don't see any issue related to your error... where do you get this error? what is the exact location in which this error manifests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, you are trying to push `New_modality` agents through a flow chart block that expects `modality` agents.

Check the flow chart block downstream of the batch block and make sure it is set to await `New_modality` agents (it is in the advanced properties)

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: However, if I want to unbatch the agents later, I should NOT create a permanent batch, right? And all agents in the batch in this case will be possible to extract from the batch with all thier properties. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, check the help on the Batch object, it is all there :)